# Compare DateTime Objects in EFCore 2.1.1 and .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to select data using EFCore 6.0 in .NET Core 2.1 trying to check whether a datetime column is less than `DateTime.Now`.

I have tried using `DbFunction.DiffMinutes()` but is of no use as I am getting no such function in the `DbFunction` class.

Any idea?

Comment: Might be prudent to add your code (as smaller broken snippet as possible, not your whole app) and be specific about your query, are you using the `DateTime` in a `Where` or a `Select`? Wording is a bit confusing.

Comment: EF Core latest (as of today) is 2.1.1. EF for .NET has a 6.0 version.

Comment: I am using latest EFCore 2.1.1, not using EF 6.0

Comment: @MelwynLobo then please update the question title + text, by [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51081271/edit) - it will be appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` v2.1.1 from Nuget Packages. Then, use `SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions` class for getting Date comparison. Do the following what I have done in my application. I have found difference in minutes between Date1 and Date2:

```
DbFunctions dfunc = null;
IQueryable<TableName> lQueryableTableName = lObjInitDbContext.gObjServerAuditHistoryDbContext
   .ServerAuditHistorys
   .Where(x => SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions
       .DateDiffMinute(dfunc, Convert.ToDateTime(Date1), Convert.ToDateTime(Date2)) < 1);
```

Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: I will try this solution and let you know, thanks for your swift reply

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

```
IQueryable<TableName> lQueryableTableName = lObjInitDbContext.gObjServerAuditHistoryDbContext
   .ServerAuditHistorys
   .Where(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(Date1, Date2) < 1);
```

Comment: A brief explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Saurabh Gupta's answer, you can also write this as follows

```
DbFunctions dbFunctions = null;
IQueryable<TableName> lQueryableTableName = lObjInitDbContext.gObjServerAuditHistoryDbContext
   .ServerAuditHistorys
   .Where(x => dbFunctions.DateDiffMinute(Convert.ToDateTime(Date1), Convert.ToDateTime(Date2)) < 1);
```

---

On a different note, does anyone know *why* the `DbFunctions` class is no longer a static class in EfCore?